# How can I simulate thermoforming?

Tags: modeling, mesh, physics

I'm trying to make a simple packaging shape : a sheet of plastic thermoformed onto a round-edged rectangle.

I've already tried this : add surface > subdivide > select the flat thermoformed faces > translation on z while proportional editing

But the shape is kinda random and isn't as crisp as I'd like.

Is there a way to apply my surface on an object, as I would drop a piece of fabric on a box, but without creasing? In other words, simulating a thermoforming ?

Thanks,

[image: side pic]

[image: tilted view of the packet]

[image: first method]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common ways to control the *crispness* that you're looking for, and either might apply here.

Both approaches start the same way:

- Create a plane.
- Add two edge loops in each direction to create a rectangle in the center. To add an edge loop, hover the mouse near one of the edges and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd>.  Move the mouse to place the loop and left click.  Right click to cancel.
- Extrude the rectangle in the Z direction.
  This will create the basic shape.  When you add a subdivision surface modifier you get something like this:

[image: the wart on the plane]

One approach is to use a bevel modifier or manual bevels along with the subdivision surface modifier.  By controlling the bevel shape and width you can control the apparent curvature. Here is how to do it.

- Add a bevel modifier *before* the subdivision surface modifier.
- Adjust the amount and number of segments to taste.

Here's a sample Bevel Modifier setup:

[image: bevel modifier]

Here's the resulting object

[image: beveled object]

By making the bevel amount smaller you will make the edge transitions more crisp.

The other approach is to use *edge loops* as *control loops* along with the subdivision surface modifier.

Here is one way to do that:

- Add two edge loops to the extruded area and place them near the corners:

[image: the first control loops]

As you can see, the blob is starting to form up.

- Add two edge loops in the Y direction, "inside" the raised area and move them near the corners:

[image: crisper blob]

As you can see the blister is looking more like the packaging.  You can move an edge loop by selecting it and tapping <kbd>g</kbd> twice.  Right Mouse Button cancels the movement, while Left Mouse Button accepts the new position.